# Issue with compiling/running a java program in xterm (python default)

Tags: bash, python, java, jre

I'm trying to run a java program using xterm. I've installed jre1.8.0_191 in `/usr/java`, but when I run `javac HelloWorld.java`. (The java file I created) I get a `/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory error`. Do I need to change the default path to JAVA? Should I have installed JDK?

Resolution:
I installed the JDK using commands found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04 and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Your java should be in `/usr/bin/` not in `/usr` . How did you install it?

Comment: I downloaded the file from https://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp, created a java folder under user, moved the file from Downloads to /usr/java/, then ran tar zxvf jre-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz to unpack the tarball and install the program. I will try moving the java folder to bin and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If you want to compile Java you need a JDK, not a JRE (the JDK includes a JRE).

Comment: Alright, I will install the jdk, thanks. Should I install it to /usr/bin/?